Supabase terminating connection and not able to load schema
I am currently working on a project and using nextjs, postgres+ prisma.
I used Supabase to create databse and used the link in my .env to connect the databse with my prisma schema.
When I am running migrate command, there is no error in terminal, and it gets connected to database, but after few minutes it gives an error on Supabase Logs section :
"Tenant has no connected users, database connection will be terminated".
I rechecked everything, my connection gets established but I am unable to understand the cause behind this disconnection.
I am attaching few screenshots, please view them for better understanding:
Real Time Log section on Supabase Dashboard
Pooler log section 
Database connection Status
This is the schema file I have written, and the Database URL is saved in .env file.
I updated all my libraries but there was no change.
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}


model User {
  id            Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  address       String         @unique
  tasks         Task[]
}

model Worker {
  id               Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  address          String      @unique
  submissions      Submission[]
  balance_id       Int 
  pending_amount   Int
  locked_amount    Int

}

model Task{
  id            Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  title         String
  user_id       Int
  user          User           @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  options       Option[]
  submissions   Submission[]
  signature     String
  amount        String
}

model Option {
  id            Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  image_url     String
  option_id     Int
  task_id       Int 
  task          Task           @relation(fields: [task_id], references: [id])
  submissions   Submission[]
}

model Submission{
  id            Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  worker_id     Int
  worker        Worker         @relation(fields: [worker_id], references: [id])
  option_id     Int
  option        Option         @relation(fields: [option_id], references: [id])
  task_id       Int
  task          Task           @relation(fields: [task_id], references: [id])
  amount        String
}


I found the issue. All I had to do was change the port number to 5432 in my postgres link.
Reference: https://supabase.com/partners/integrations/prisma#connection-pooling-with-supabase
